# Converting PHP JSON data to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a generated JSON PHP data which I receive in JavaScript as an Object via an AJAX request and try to convert to an array.

For example, I may have this (not real data):

```
Array[1]
    0:Object
        items: Object
            0: "First data item"
            1: "Second data item"
            __proto__: Object
                Some unimportant getter functions
        __proto__: Object
            Some unimportant getter functions
        length: 1
        __proto__: Object
            Some functions
```

I am able to convert the outside portion into an array, but how do I convert the inner parts (especially the dictionary at `items:Object`) into arrays as well?

## UPDATE

My structure has changed

```
Array[1]
    title:#data
```

Comment: In PHP create an associative array then use `json_encode(...);` to encode the data and return it in the proper format for the javascript.

Comment: If the PHP data is an array, it should be encoded as a JSON array. The PHP data must not have been an ordinary array if you got an object when you decoded it.

Comment: @War10ck That seems to be the opposite of what he wants. He's getting an object, he wants an array.

Comment: You're using `json_encode` in the PHP, and `JSON.parse` in the Javascript, aren't you?

Comment: @Barmar In that case, the OP should be able to create a regular array `$out[] = "First data item"; $out[] = "Second data item";` and then return that data with _json_encode()_ like so `echo json_encode($out);` right?...

Comment: We need to see the PHP code that's constructing the data and returning the JSON.

Comment: I confirmed the validity of the PHP through multiple tests using POST requests from Python and answers to a previous question I asked. I make an array, and `echo json_encode($data)`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am using `$.parseJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the server script that outputs the JSON, it would be better to format the data into the actual format you want to use.

But if you want to convert an object property values into an array you can do it by setting a `length` property on the object and then using [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on the [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method. In order to do this the object property names have to be numerical (ie 0,1,2,3 etc) any that are not will not be added to the array automatically.

```js
var data = [
  { 
    items:{
      0: "Item 1",
      1: "Item 2",
      2: "Item 3",
      3: "Item 4",
    }
  },
  { 
    items:{
      0: "Item 5",
      1: "Item 6",
    }
  }  
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var items = data[i].items;
  items.length = Object.keys(items).length;
  data[i].items = [].slice.call(items,0);
}
console.log(data);
document.body.innerHTML=JSON.stringify (data);
```

if your object property names are not numerical you would have to do a loop and add each value to an array manually

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var items = data[i].items;
  var itemArray = [];
  Object.keys(items).forEach(function(key){
     itemArray.push( items[key] );
  });
  data[i].items = itemArray;
}
```

Comment: I get no output from this whatsoever

Comment: OK, I have confirmed through alerts that the loop you put doesn't even start 0.0

Comment: Works for me in the F12 developer tools console (IE11): {
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   items: [
      0: "Item 1",
      1: "Item 2",
      2: "Item 3",
      3: "Item 4",
      length: 4
   ]
}

Comment: Ah I think I got it, the value of the key is also an Object to be made into an array. I think I have to reverse the order, get the object of the keys and then iterate over them. Would that work?